# read csv with quotes seperator using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When reading this wine csv document: [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG35j.jpg) using pandas as follow :

```
import pandas as pd
wine = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';')
```

It returns to me the following :[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsAJ1.jpg)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you try `pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';', quoting=3)` ?

Comment: Yes. It is working now with quoting. But why is it not working without it ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is some columns values are with quoiting `"`, some not. So pandas incorrect parse them.

Solution is remove quoting by `quoting=3` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';', quoting=3)
```